# Linq expression over a list of derived types

Tags: linq

I am trying to write a Linq expression that checks against property in a derived class, but the list is made up of members from a base class.  Example code below.  The 2nd line of the Process method starting with 'var list' does not compile, but I am not sure what syntax I should use to make it valid?

```
public class Manager
{
    public void Process()
    {
        Base[] stuff = { new Derived() { Id = "1", Name = "me" } };

        var list = stuff.Where<Derived>(d => d.Name == "me");
    }
}

public class Base
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know the list has only `Derived`, you can use the `Cast<T>` method:

```
var list = stuff.Cast<Derived>().Where(d => d.Name == "me");
```

If there are only *some* `Derived`, you can use `OfType<T>`:

```
var list = stuff.OfType<Derived>().Where(d => d.Name == "me");
```

In that case, the non-`Derived` objects will be skipped.